# Typescript: Typing a function that returns a subset of an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, types, subset

I'm trying to type a function that returns a subset of the properties of an object that it is given. I'm not sure why the following does not work.

```
const initialState = {
  count: 0,
  mounted: false,
}

type State = Readonly<typeof initialState>

type Updater<S> = <K extends keyof S>(prevState: S) => Pick<S, K> | null

const increment/* ERROR HERE */: Updater<State> = (prevState: State) => ({
  count: prevState.count + 1,
})
```

I get the following error.

```
Type '{ count: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Readonly<{ count: number; mounted: boolean; }>, K>'.
```

This typing of the setState method from react seems to work well

```
class Component<P, S> {
    ...
    setState<K extends keyof S>(
        state: ((prevState: Readonly<S>, props: P) => (Pick<S, K> | S | null)) | (Pick<S, K> | S | null),
        callback?: () => void
    ): void;
    ...
}
```

and

```
setState(increment)
```

works without any errors.

The types seem quite similar so I'm not quite sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `increment` returns a specific subset of the keys of `State`. An `Updater` function would need to return a subset of the keys of `State` based not on it's own logic but based on the type parameter passed to it.

If we don't care what subset of `State` is returned we could use `Partial<T>` but this would make the function useless for `setState` which my guess is the point:

```
type State = Readonly<typeof initialState>

type Updater<S> = (prevState: S) => Partial<S> | null

const increment: Updater<State> = (prevState: State) => ({
count: prevState.count + 1,
})

class Foo extends React.Component<{}, typeof initialState>
{
    foo(){
        this.setState(increment(this.state)); // Would be an error because count  is number | undefined
    }
}
```

Antother option is to fix in `Updater` the keys which the function need to return by moving the type parameter to `Updater` from the function :

```
type Updater<S, K extends keyof S> = (prevState: S) => Pick<S, K> | null

const increment: Updater<State, 'count'> = (prevState: State) => ({
    count: prevState.count + 1,
})
```

This allows us to use the function in `setState` but we need to specify the type parameter explicitly. The best option is to use a factory function that would infer `K` for us.

```
type Updater<S, K extends keyof S> = (prevState: S) => Pick<S, K> | null

function createUpdater<S>() {
    return function<K extends keyof S> (fn: (state: S) => Pick<S, K>) : Updater<S, K> {
        return fn;
    }
} 
const increment  = createUpdater<State>()((prevState: State) => ({
    count: prevState.count + 1,
}));
```

Although the best solution might be not specify the type of `increment` at all and let the compiler deal with all the types.